# hdfs recovering after data node failure

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a 4 node hadoop cluster with 2 master node and 2 data nodes. I have lot of files in this cluster. One of my data node got crashed ( Terminated accidentally from aws console ). Since I had replication factor 1 I assume this doesn't cause any data loss. I added new node and made it as data node. But now my `hdfs dfsadmin -report` says lot of missing blocks. Why is this ? How can I recover from here ? I cannot do fsck -delete as these files are important for me. When I tried distcp from this cluster to another newly created cluster I get missing block exceptions. Do I need to do any step after adding new data node ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended replication factor on Hadoop is 3. With a value of 1, you don't get any replica at all hence you've lost some data!

Comment: Ooh. Thanks for the reply. I have the data in my EBS volume which is not deleted. Can I get it back from it ? Could you please tell me the step ? If I copy the data from EBS volume to datanode directory of the live node will it work ?

Comment: you would recover raw files, but probably not HDFS files. Worth trying..

Comment: @Bill the datanodes store blocks, not whole, raw files. Copying files directly into that local datanode directory also won't cause the namenode to recognize them when you do HDFS operations

Comment: Harold: Thanks. Let me try this out.
@cricket_007: I think on cluster start up data node sends blocks they have and name node understand these mapping. Let me try this out.

Comment: @BillGoldberg I don't think that's right. For example, if I copy `foo.txt` into `datanode.dirs`, then reboot everything, then run `hdfs -ls`, that file will not appear because I didn't copy it into any **specific** HDFS location

Comment: No no. I am talking different thing. I have foo.txt properly loaded in my hdfs cluster. Say for eg few blocks in datanode1 and others in datanode2. If I kill the datanode1 and start a new one with copying datanode1's data directory ( Second blocks of foo.txt ). I assume I would be able to get the file properly via hdfs.

Comment: Well, no. Unless the NameNode believes that your new datanode is datanode1, and unless nothing was altered in HDFS metadata since the corruption.

Comment: How or where is this mapping ( new datanode -> datanode1 ) being tracked by namenode ? Any idea ? Will there be say private ip / hostname mapping ?

Comment: I tried recovering from data node data directories but my namenode is still in safe mode for the past 24 hours. So probably I lost the data or need to investigate further. Accepting the above answer. Thanks again all of us.